# In output why the value of x decreases to 2

Tags: c

I have just started to learn the 'C' language. I was practicing some problems and faced this doubt.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{ 
    int x=4, y, z;
    y=--x;
    z=x--;
    printf("%d %d %d\n", x, y, z);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: x is decremented twice, 4-2=2.

Comment: What would you expect instead?

Comment: As I read the code, it should print 3, 3, 2.

Answer (score 0):

Here, `x` is decremented once: `y=--x;`.
Here, it is decremented the second time: `z=x--;`.
It starts off as 4, from init here `int x=4`.

The result is 2.